# Equation for tension on a spherical pendulum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

I'm trying to write a program to do a simulation I saw on a [YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C5Jkgvw-Z6E) recently, where essentially I need to simulate a spherical pendulum where the mass on the end of it is also pulled by several magnets. My current method is (for each time step):

1. Find a vector $F$, of the total force applied by all of the magnets.
2. Add the weight of the mass to $F$.
3. Under the assumption that the tension in the string of the pendulum was equal to the parallel component of $F$, we came up with a formula to work out the result force.

Once we had the final resultant force, we calculated the acceleration and then added this to the current velocity of the pendulum. Then we simply added the velocity to the position, and rendered the pendulum on the screen.

It's difficult to describe what the output looks like, but safe to say it behaves nothing like a pendulum. It does sort of swing left to right, but flies straight down, stretching the string very far.

Since then, we have realised the flaw in our assumption. We looked at a diagram of the movement and acceleration of a pendulum and realised the acceleration has to be completely different to how it was in our simulation.

We have looked around the internet but haven't found a suitable equation - does anyone know how to calculate the tension in the string of a spherical pendulum? Once we have the tension, we can easily add up all the forces and move the pendulum correctly.

Comment: Is this a fully 3D pendulum, or is it _constrained_ to move in a plane?

Answer (score 0):

My suggest:

Assume the string length of the pendulum is  constant as usual. Starting from the initial position, calculate the net force, the sum of magnetic forces and the gravitational force. Find the component of the net force perpendicular to the string (defined by the current position and the position of the fixed-end of the pendulum). The component parallel to the string will be cancelled by the tension of the string. The movement to the next position will then be determined by this perpendicular component.

\begin{array}
\vec{r}_0\,\, \text{fixed end of the string } = &\, (0,0,0);\\
\text{current position of the pendulum  } & \vec{r} =\, (x,y,z) - (0,0,0)=(x,y,z).\\
\text{unit vector  } & \hat{r} =\, \vec{r}\, / \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}.\\
\text{constrain } : &\, \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} = \ell_0 = \text{string length}.\\
\text{net force  }\,\, & \, \vec{F} =\, \vec{F}_1 + \vec{F}_2 + \vec{F}_3 + \vec{F}_g .\\
\text{parallel component  } &\, F_\parallel = \vec{F}\cdot\hat{r}.\\
\text{perpendicular component  } &\, \vec{F}_\perp = \vec{F} -F_\parallel \,\hat{r}.\\
\text{movement of position } & \Delta{\vec{r}} =\, \Delta{\vec{r}}\left( \vec{r},\vec{v},\vec{F}_\perp \right)\\
\text{next position  } & \vec{r}(t+\Delta t) =\, \vec{r} + \Delta\vec{r};\\
\text{re-normalization } & \vec{r}(t+\Delta t) \to \, \ell_0 \,\hat{r}(t+\Delta t).\\
\end{array}